# Angular: text input won't set to a default value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, textinput

I have this 'Username' input:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="userName">Username</label>
    <input name='userName' ngModel id="userName" type="text" 
           ng-model="userName"   init="userName='Bob'" value="Bob" >
</div>
```

I want to set the input to 'Bob' by default but this doesn't work. If i delete 'ngModel' it works and I need it otherwise it won't sent my username to server.

This is in the begging of the form(the action that happens when I press submit button):

```
<form #physicians="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(physicians.value)">
```

And this the controller:

```
onFormSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.adminService.updateUser(data).subscribe((responseData: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
   },
   (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
       this.isSignupError = true;
       this.errorText = err.error['message'];
   });
}
```

How can I fix this?Thank you!

Comment: which angular version you are using

Comment: Angular 6 is what I use.

Comment: then why not you  use formcontrolname

Comment: I don't know exactly how. I google it now.

Comment: let me give you code  for that

Comment: ok:).Thank you.

Comment: is this working ????

Comment: Angular 2 onward don't have the ng-model attribute, only ngModel. You should also specify the bindings in your HTML code by surrounding your attributes with (round) and [square] brackets. In the case of  ngModel, you almost always want the bindings to be two-directional, so it should be `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like:

ts code:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  userName;
  constructor() {
    this.userName = 'Bob';
  }
}
```

html:

```
 <form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
    <label>userName:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userName" required minlength="2" maxlength="10" #userNameDir="ngModel">
    <pre>errors: {{userNameDir.errors | json}}</pre>
  <button type="button" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="onFormSubmit(form.value)">submit</button>
  <pre>form.value: {{form.value | json}}</pre>
  <pre>form.errors: {{form.errors | json}}</pre>
  <pre>form.status: {{form.status | json}}</pre>
  <pre>form.dirty:{{form.dirty | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-basic-template-driven-oqbj8s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[defaultValue]="myDefaultValue"
```

without Angular changing the variable 'myDefaultValue' on the input change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:
**HTML**:

```
<input name='userName'  id="userName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="userName">
```

**TS**:

```
userName='Bob' // when you have declared the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form [formGroup]="physicians" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(physicians.value)">
<div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="userName">Username</label>
            <input  name='userName'  type="text"  formControlName="userName"  >
     </div>
```

***TS FILE code***

Put this in ngOnInit

```
this.physicians= this._formBuilder.group({
      userName:['bob']
})



onFormSubmit(data) {
console.log(data);
 this.adminService.updateUser(data).subscribe((responseData: any) => {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
},
(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  this.isSignupError = true;
  this.errorText = err.error['message'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add  this.userName = 'Bob'; in the file .ts  , remove init and value='Bob' from html.